# Ambiguous pow() function

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a simple call to the `pow()` function from math.h someihing similar to..

```
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    float v,w;
    w=3.0;
    v=pow(w,0.5);//i think this is 'float pow(float,float)'
    return 0;
}
```

but visual studio says it's an error

```
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\deo\deo\main.cpp(7) : error C2666: 'pow' : 6 overloads have similar conversions
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\math.h(575): could be 'long double pow(long double,int)'
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\math.h(573): or       'long double pow(long double,long double)'
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\math.h(527): or       'float pow(float,int)'
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\math.h(525): or       'float pow(float,float)'
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\math.h(489): or       'double pow(double,int)'
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\math.h(123): or       'double pow(double,double)'
1>        while trying to match the argument list '(float, double)'
```

I thought I had the format `float pow(float, float)`.

Comment: Read the last line of that error message.  0.5 is considered a double, and the compiler can't figure out what to auto-recast it to since there are several casts that it could do that would work.

Comment: I'm removing the `c` tag because this is unique to `c++`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the line:

```
v=pow(w,0.5);
```

`w` is a float and `0.5` is a `double`. You can use `0.5f` instead.

Comment: Yeah..you were trying to call `pow(float,double)`. The compiler doesn't know if you want to cast that to `pow(float,float)` (loss of precision) or `pow(double,double)`. Actually... I don't know why it doesn't choose the second one... probably because the function might be something different entirely.

Comment: It doesn't choose the second one because it doesn't know that the semantics are good enough in practice for most uses, and it isn't worth teaching it because definitely can't manage the corner cases. For example, if the result of the first one would be out of range, downstream code might depend on that behaviour. Humans should make decisions; compilers should implement them.

Answer (score 5):

Math functions like pow(), sin() etc are templatized in more modern C++ implementations.  The reason it is ambiguous is that it is unclear what you want to do. If you send in both arguments being the same, you presumably want the computation to be done at that specific precision. If they are different, then do you want to compute at the higher precision and upcast the lower precision operand, or do you want to downcast the higher precision to lower precision and then do the computation at lower precision. i.e.

```
float a,b;
double c,d;
pow(a,b); // not ambiguous, done at float precision
pow(c,d); // not ambiguous, done at double precision
pow(a,c); // ambiguous, gives error
pow((double)a,c); // not ambiguous, performs computation at double precision
pow(a,(float)c); // not ambiguous, gives computation at float precision, but c might lose precision in the down cast
```

Answer (score 2):

Try 
`v=pow(w,0.5f);`

Answer (score 2):

`0.5` is of type double. Try

```
v=pow(w,0.5f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey, have you tried 0.5f?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all other methods that already were given in the other answers, you could always explicitly specify template argument:

```
float w = 3.0f;
double v = 1.5;
v = pow<float>(w, v);
```